# Access SQL query select with a specific pattern

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to select each 5 rows to be unique and the select pattern applies for the rest of the result (i.e if the result contains 10 records I am expecting to have 2 set of 5 unique rows)

Example:

- What I have:

  - 1
  - 1

    5

    3

    4

    5

    2

    4

    2

    3
- Result I want to achieve:

  - 1
  - 2

    3

    4

    5

    1

    2

    3

    4

    5

I have tried and searched a lot but couldn't find anything close to what I want to achieve.

Comment: "I  want to select each 5 rows". Next: "it doesn't matter if the result is 2x5 or 2x6". So what do you want?

Comment: @Gustav looks you haven't understood my question at the first place, the 2x5 was only an example, I only want to select rows with the specific pattern that repeats for the rest of the result table.

Comment: Yes, I must admit I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can somehow order the rows within the sets of 5:

```
SELECT  t.Row % 5, t.Row FROM #T t
ORDER BY  t.Row , t.Row % 5
```

We could probably get closer to the truth with more details about what your data looks like and what it is you're trying to actually do.

Answer (score 0):

This will work with the sample of data you provided

```
SELECT DISTINCT(thevalue) FROM theresults

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT(thevalue) FROM theresults
```

But it's unclear to me if it's really what you need.

For instance :

- if your table/results returns 12 rows, do you still want 2x5 rows or do you want 2x6 rows ?
- do you have always in your table/results the same rows in double ?

There's a lot more questions to rise and no hint about them in what you asked.

Comment: thank you for your answer, my table is a fixed size around 120 records, it doesn't matter if the result is 2x5 or 2x6, the only thing I am seeking for is the select by pattern like that, and union doesn't work for my case, thank you.